# socket bind on beaglebone not taking input

Tags: python, sockets

So I'm creating a socket interface between my computer an a beaglebone Black.  I have successfully been able to send information from the beaglebone to my computer but i am unable to send information back, i get the following error.

```
Socket created
Socket bind complete
Socket now listening
Connected to 192.168.0.120:49378
main:: Begin program...
Residual System Status: startup

Please address errors. Continue? (Y/N) 

y
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\Desktop\miles_lybrairy\milesintegration_V0.0.3\MILES\sockettoem.py:41 in <module>
    s.send(bytes(input(),'UTF-8'))

OSError: [WinError 10057] A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied
```

here is the code for my beaglebone

```
import Adafruit_BBIO.ADC as ADC
import time
import socket
import sys
import os

serverAddr = ('192.168.0.11', 20103)

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(serverAddr)

fsr = 'P9_40'

ADC.setup()

while True:
        reading = ADC.read(fsr)*1000
        reading = int(round(reading))
        stdout =os.system("python3 ./fw102c_control.py")
        
        #client.send(bytes("poop"))
        client.recv(1024)
client.close()
```

here is the code for my computer

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Aug 15 13:56:19 2022

@author: GigaGame
"""


import socket
import sys
import os

HOST = ''
PORT = 20103



s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print('Socket created')

try:
        s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as msg:
        print('Bind failed. ')
        sys.exit()

print('Socket bind complete')


s.listen(10)
print('Socket now listening')

conn, addr = s.accept()
print('Connected to ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1]))

while True:
        
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        line = data.decode('UTF-8')    # convert to string (Python 3 only)
        print( line )

        s.send(bytes(input(),'UTF-8'))
        #s.recv()
```

I have attempted to make my beaglebone post what my computer outputs and it functions.  This is just a test code, I'm using a redirect function for output as well on the beaglebone but I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do here `s.send(bytes(input(),'UTF-8'))` but `s` is the listening socket, it's listening for new connections. `conn` is the actual socket that is connected to a peer, so you probably meant to have `conn.send(bytes(input(),'UTF-8'))`

Comment: Maybe its the HOST = ''. Try specifying `localhost` or the `address` of the server.

Comment: tried conn, it did not seem to progress the program, it just hangs up like its not getting input. specified the host I got the same error i did originally.

Comment: just tried client.sendto(bytes(input(''),'UTF-8'),('192.168.0.120',20103)), got same os error OSError: [WinError 10057] A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied

Comment: I'm wondering if its the program on the beaglebone, the main program is set up for the socket but the program requires input for a definition that is being called from a diferent python script, could it be that the definition itself is not taking input though the main program is taking inputs?